# Azure B2C User Flow doesn't return back to the mobile app in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, appauth

I am using the following package to integrate Azure B2C User flow in React Native Mobile App.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-auth?activeTab=readme

On Android, the user flow works fine and I am able to receive the idtoken in the app.

In iOS , I am redirected to B2c policy , from there I select any IDP such as Google, I go to the IDP sing in , enter the credentials and then nothing happens.

I have done the Setup related steps mentioned in the package documentation.
But I can feel that the authorize function never returns back to the app
I neither get an error nor the token

```
try {
  console.log("before calling autorize");
  const result = await authorize(config);
  console.log("Result Object : ",result);
  const authToken = result.idToken;
  console.log("ID TOKEN : " , authToken);
  const decodedToken = jwt_decode(authToken);
  return decodedToken;
 
  
  // result includes accessToken, accessTokenExpirationDate and refreshToken
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error occured");
  console.log(error);
}
```

I even tried to change to a custom policy with App insights integrated, but I could not find any errors or traces for the custom policy
I will be grateful if I can get any pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: I see the following message in the logs :  BackgroundTask] Background Task 2 ("Called by rncoretestb2c, from -[RNAppAuth authorizeWithConfiguration:redirectUrl:clientId:clientSecret:scopes:useNonce:usePKCE:additionalParameters:skipCodeExchange:iosCustomBrowser:prefersEphemeralSession:resolve:reject:]"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.
It was just a missing '/' at the end of the redirect uri for iOS
I am now wondering why this is not mentioned anywhere in the docs.
It is only mentioned as 'Important' at the end of the sample for AD.

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/main/docs/config-examples/azure-active-directory.md

[image]

For example in Azure App config if the redirect uri is  com.bundleid://auth

In the mobile app config it should be com.bundleid://auth/